# Ubuntu Laggy Response over time 64bit

Tags: nvidia, hard-drive, ssd

Hello everyone here are my specs:

- i7 2600 intel cpu
- asus p8p67 motherboard
- 8gb ram kingston
- ocz agility 240gb ssd
- 1tb seagate hdd 7200rpm
- 800w corsair psu
- evga nvidia gtx680 2gb

I am running on an ASUS 27Inch 2560x1440p monitor.

I have windows 7 running on my seagate hdd. I installed 64 bit 13.04 ubuntu on the ssd. grub allows me to choose between the two and that is working fine. Ubuntu runs very well when I start using it. But then over time the performance starts to deteriorate.

So when I am typing this out now it lags, when I grab a window and move it around it lags. So there seems to be a delay to my actions. If I reboot and log in again it runs fine but then the same problem occurs. If I leave idle for an hour and come back performance suffers?

I installed the latest NVIDIA drivers thinking it may of fixed the problem. To me it seems like some sort of bottlenecking occurs over time? I check the RAM and processes and nothing looks out of the ordinary, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was change my NVIDIA driver and now it runs well:

1. Go to top left icon and search for Software and Updates.
2. Click on software and updates
3. Go to the tab named Additional Drivers
4. I originally had NVIDIA binary Xorg, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-304 (proprietary) OPTION 5.
5. I changed to NVIDIA binary Xorg, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-310-updates (proprietary, tested)
6. Rebooted the system
7. Performs excellent now